# angular, apollo-client, graphQL - Select all fields from a graphql query

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, graphql, apollo-client

I query a graphql service with apollo-client and angular4 giving it the fieldnames I want to retrieve by an array that can also be null. If Array fields is null  I want my client to return all fieldnames available by the graphQL method. By now I have to write them by hand. Is it possible to select all fieldnames by default?

Or is my code totally bad and there are some best practises out there to handle dynamic graphql queries?

Example goes here:

```
//...

function fieldsToModel(fields: Array<any>, output: string): string {

  for (const field in fields) {

    if (typeof fields[field] !== 'object') {
      output += fields[field].toString() + ',';
    } else {
      if (Object.keys(fields[field])[0] !== undefined) {
        output += Object.keys(fields[field])[0] + '{' + fieldsToModel(fields[field][Object.keys(fields[field])[0]], '') + '},';
      }
    }
  }

  return output;
}

// ...

public GetPersons(
    personId: number, repId: number, fields: Array<any> = null): Observable<PersonModel> {

    fields = fields !== null ? fields : [
      'id', '', 'firstname', 'repId', 'lastname', 'sex',
      { 'adress': ['street', 'zip', 'city'] },'birthday'];

    const head: String = `query GetPersons($repId:String, $personId:String, $Token:String) 
    { viewer { GetPersons(repId: $repId, personId: $personId, Token: $Token) {`;
    let body = '';
    body = fieldsToModel(fields, body);
    const foot: String = '}}}';
    const query = head + body + foot;

    return this._apollo.watchQuery<any>({
      query: gql`${query}`,
      variables: {
        repID: Id.toString(),
        personId: personId.toString(),
        Token: environment.Secret
      },
    })
      .map(result => this._processGetPerson(result))
      .catch((response_: any) => {
        try {
          return this._processGetPerson(response_);
        } catch (e) {
          return <Observable<PersonModel>><any>Observable.throw(e);
        }
      });
  }

  private _processGetPerson(result: any): any {
    if (result.graphQLErrors) {
      return Observable.throw(result);
    }

    const person = new PersonModel();
    if (result.data && result.data.viewer && result.data.viewer.GetPerson) {
      person.init(result.data.viewer.GetPerson);
    }
    return person;
  }

// ...
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query for all the fields first and use the result to query all fields:

```
{ __type(name:"Person") {
    fields {
      name
      }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But what if I dont know the names of all the fields?

Comment: This query gives you all the field names of the `Person` type.

Comment: But isn't it costly?